# How to use free tab bar icon images as bar button image?

Tags: ios, icons, uibarbuttonitem, tabbar

I got some free image icons for iOS, for example, http://glyphish.com/

but I think these images is for tab bar icons, not for bar button images. I used these images to bar button, but it isn't good to look due to alphas in image. Pure-white image is needed for bar button image.

1. Is there any good images for bar button?
2. or, how can I edit image to use in bar button image? I'm not familiar to graphics tools like photoshop.
3. or, can I use images by changing bar button properties? I think if images can be inverted, it'll be better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are developing an HTML/CSS/Javascript app - have you looked at [Jquery Mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com)?

You can use their standard bar icons, which are white with alpha background - see the JQM-docs on button icons [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html).

So regarding your questions:

1) Yes, you can for example stick with the custom icons provided by frameworks
2) You can always draw your own icons in Photoshop or (I prefer) Inkscape (free & easier). I did [this](http://www.franckreich.de/3/IMG/themes/tinyicons-18C.png) in Inkscape for example. Works nicely in Jquery Mobile.
3) Inverting images - if you are talking about using an image as a "mask" - you can only do this on Webkit browsers using the `-webkit-mask-image` property without changing the icon (example: [here](http://jordandobson.com/webkit_mask_iphone_nav/). If you need this across different devices, you have to cut out icons from a background-image. I did this in my [cross-browser tab-bar](http://www.stokkers.mobi/valuables/bartender.html)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, but I'm working for images for pure-application of iOS. My question is actually "how to edit image with photoshop", I think I'd better ask to my designer friend next to my desk. I feel sorry to say that.

Comment: no problem :-) I have been using both photoshop and inkscape for icons. If you are not doing gradient backgrounds, I think Inkscape is easier to use for the once-in-a-while-user. Good luck.